# Literal tool to create dynamic textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to create textbox dynamically using literal tool but textbox is not executing. Please help.

```
<tr>
    <td><p>Number of days taken : </p></td>
    <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtLeaveTakenDays"  Width="210" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="DayButton" runat="server" Text="Enter Date" 
                onclick="DayButton_Click" />
    </td>

</tr>
```

In the DayButton click event here is aspx.cs code

```
int DaysEnter = Convert.ToInt32(txtLeaveTakenDays.Text);
StringBuilder put;
put = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < DaysEnter; i++)
{             
   put.Append("<tr><td style=\"text-align:right;\"><p>Day " + (i+1) + " : </p></td><td><asp:TextBox ID=\"DayDateDay" + (i+1) + "\" Width=\"210\" runat=\"server\"  style=\"text-align:center;\"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>");
}
DayDateLiteral.Text = put.ToString();
```

It displays text correctly but does not show the TextBox.. Please Help
[image: As shown here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because you cannot create controls from a string inside a literal control. There are a couple of ways you can achieve what you want.

If you do not need server side functionality attached to the generated textbox, then you could do it all through jQuery.

e.g.

```
<tr>
    <td><p>Number of days taken : </p></td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLeaveTakenDays" ClientIDMode="Static"  Width="210" runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="DayButton" runat="server" Text="Enter Date" onclientclick="addTR()" />
    </td> 
</tr>

<script>
    function addTR() {
        var days = $('#txtLeaveTakenDays').text();
        $('tr:last-of-type').append("<tr><td style='text-align:right;''><p>Day " + days + " : </p></td><td><input type='text' id='DayDateDay" + days + "' style='text-align:center;' width='210' text='" + days + "' /></td></tr>);
    }
</script>
```

If you want to programmatically add server controls, you need to create the controls first in your codebehind and then add it to another server control already on the page - the example below adds in a table tag and makes that a server-side control.

HTML

```
<table id="DayTable" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Number of days taken : </p></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLeaveTakenDays" ClientIDMode="Static"  Width="210" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="DayButton" runat="server" Text="Enter Date" onclick="DayButton_Click" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

VB

```
Protected Sub DayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim TR As New HtmlTableRow

    Dim TD1 As New HtmlTableCell
    TD1.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:right;")
    TD1.InnerHtml = "<p>Day " & txtLeaveTakenDays.Text & " : </p>"
    Dim TD2 As New HtmlTableCell

    Dim TB As New TextBox
    TB.ID = "DayDateDay" & txtLeaveTakenDays.Text
    TB.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:center;")
    TB.Width = 210
    TB.Text = txtLeaveTakenDays.Text

    TD2.Controls.Add(TB)
    TR.Controls.Add(TD1)
    TR.Controls.Add(TD2)

    DayTable.Controls.Add(TR)

End Sub
```

C#

```
protected void DayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlTableRow TR = new HtmlTableRow;
    HtmlTableCell TD1 = new HtmlTableCell;
    TD1.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:right;");
    TD1.InnerHtml = "<p>Day " + txtLeaveTakenDays.Text + " : </p>";
    HtmlTableCell TD2 = new HtmlTableCell;
    TextBox TB = new TextBox;
    TB.ID = "DayDateDay" + txtLeaveTakenDays.Text;
    TB.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:center;");
    TB.Width = 210;
    TB.Text = txtLeaveTakenDays.Text;
    TD2.Controls.Add(TB);
    TR.Controls.Add(TD1);
    TR.Controls.Add(TD2);
    DayTable.Controls.Add(TR);
}
```

The VB / C# code creates each td, the textbox, and the new tr as controls, and then adds them to the table. This way, you will then be able to access the generated textbox from your code behind.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `PlaceHolderControl` to add dynamic controls to the page. See this [link](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Using-PlaceHolder-Control.aspx) for a sample on how to do it.

Comment: Please don't link to external sites unless the link is there to support content already in your answer.